# Button checking with fire event

Tags: reactjs, testing

```
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };  
<span
       role="button"
       tabIndex={0}
       className="see-more"
       data-testid="see-more-button"
       onClick={togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup}
  >
```

test file to check by fire event

```
test("should render see more as a button when text length is greater than 50", async () => {
    const togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <UpcomingEventCard
        event={{
          ...upComingEvent,
          purposeAndObjective: "Placeholder".repeat(15),
        }}
        togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup={togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup}
      />
    );
    const seeMoreButton = getByTestId("see-more-button");
    fireEvent.click(seeMoreButton);
    expect(togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

getting error while checking if see more button is fired
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)

```
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to the usage of togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup function, it looks like you are providing the function to UpcomingEventCard component as a prop but it's not been used directly in the component.

Try this code instead:

```
const UpcomingEventCard = (
{event, togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup}) => {
return(
 <div>
   <span
       role="button"
       tabIndex={0}
       className="see-more"
       data-testid="see-more-button"
       onClick={togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup}
  >
See More
</span>
</div>
)
}
```

ensure that the UpcomingEventCard component uses the provider togglePurposeAndObjectivePopup prop when the button is clicked
when you make these changes your test should work perfectly